# can't find buffered temporary file of nginx

Tags: nginx

I got following warning from Nginx error log when I'm uploading a large file (5GB),

`2014/06/09 22:30:13 [warn] 14170#0: *3 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001, client: 10.170.24.90, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "POST files/test_file HTTP/1.1", host: "10.119.140.39"`

The interesting part is I can't find the temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001

`ls: cannot access /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001: No such file or directory`

All the temp path settings are default, anyone knows where to find the temp file?

Answer (score 0):

Temp file was deleted immediately after sending it to backend or after closing client`s session if file wasn`t uploaded.
If you can`t uploading file, check if nginx has access to write into /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/.

Comment: the file was uploaded successfully. i just can't find it while the uploading is in process

Comment: Excuse me for delay with answer. With my config I find file in directory that written in error.log. May be `lsof | grep nginx | grep temp`  while uploading can help you.